# How to ignore http response errors when call APIs angular

Tags: angular

***How I can ignore HTTP response errors and return the response as is from API call  in angular 5***
I'm using angular HTTP client and this is my code for calling APIs

*Api Handler*:

```
get<T>(url:string):Observable<T> {

    return this.http.get<T>(url, this.getRequestHeaders()).pipe<T>(
      catchError(error => {
        return this.handleError(error, () => this.get(url));
      }));
  }
```

*Handle Error*:

```
protected handleError(error, continuation: () => Observable<any>) {
    if (error.status == 401) {
        if (this.isRefreshingLogin) {
            return this.pauseTask(continuation);
        }
        this.isRefreshingLogin = true;

        return this.authService.refreshLogin().pipe(
            mergeMap(data => {
                this.isRefreshingLogin = false;
                this.resumeTasks(true);

            return continuation();
        }),
        catchError(refreshLoginError => {
          this.isRefreshingLogin = false;
          this.resumeTasks(false);

          if (refreshLoginError.status == 401 || (refreshLoginError.url && refreshLoginError.url.toLowerCase().includes(this.loginUrl.toLowerCase()))) {
            this.authService.reLogin();
            return throwError('session expired');
          }
          else {
            return throwError(refreshLoginError || 'server error');
          }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @DZDomi I updated my question, this is my code for catch error but I want if the status code is 404 or 400 return response that came from API  as is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue your normal flow on an error code of 404 and 400 you just need to return a false Observable when you encounter this codes, like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
...
protected handleError(error, continuation: () => Observable<any>) {
    if (error.status == 404 || error.status == 400) {
        return of(false);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when adding your code it gives me an error on (.of)  Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Comment: Thanks for the answer now (of) work but when checking data returned from API I found it equal (false)

Comment: Thanks for the answer everything works perfectly now when return (of(error.error))